# In WPF, when using a DataGrid in another DataGrid's DataGridTemplateColumn, can I customize columns?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, datagrid, datagridtemplatecolumn

So I have the following data grid, bound to some dynamic data:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="dataGrid" AutoGenerateColumns="False" ColumnHeaderStyle="{StaticResource timmy}">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="First Name" Binding="{Binding FirstName}"></DataGridTextColumn>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Last Name" Binding="{Binding LastName}"></DataGridTextColumn>
        <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Cars">
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Cars}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" Margin="-10,-3,-10,-5" ColumnHeaderStyle="{StaticResource timmy2}">
                        <DataGrid.Columns>
                            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Brand" Binding="{Binding Brand}" Width="170"></DataGridTextColumn>
                            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Model" Binding="{Binding Model}" Width="170"></DataGridTextColumn>
                        </DataGrid.Columns>
                    </DataGrid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

This prototype works well, but I now need to populate the inner DataGrid's columns at runtime. I know I can set a DataGridTemplateColumn programmatically like so:

```
DataGridTemplateColumn gridColumn = new DataGridTemplateColumn();
gridColumn.Header = key;
gridColumn.Width = DataGridLength.Auto;
gridColumn.MinWidth = 160.0;

var dataGridFactory = new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(DataGrid));
gridColumn.CellTemplate = new DataTemplate() { VisualTree = dataGridFactory };

this.resultsDataGrid.Columns.Add(gridColumn);
```

However, since I'm dealing with a factory, how can I set my columns?

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution. I had to create a custom XAML string in code and then use a XamlReader to read it:

```
DataGridTemplateColumn gridColumn = new DataGridTemplateColumn();
gridColumn.Header = patientColumnName;
gridColumn.Width = DataGridLength.Auto;

StringBuilder xamlBuilder = new StringBuilder();
xamlBuilder.AppendLine("<DataTemplate xmlns=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation\">");
xamlBuilder.AppendLine("    <DataGrid ItemsSource = \"{Binding Visits}\" AutoGenerateColumns = \"False\" Margin = \"-10,-3,-10,-5\">");
xamlBuilder.AppendLine("        <DataGrid.Columns>");
// Put whatever here.
xamlBuilder.AppendLine("        </DataGrid.Columns>");
xamlBuilder.AppendLine("    </DataGrid>");
xamlBuilder.AppendLine("</DataTemplate>");

DataTemplate dataTemplate = XamlReader.Parse(xamlBuilder.ToString()) as DataTemplate;

gridColumn.CellTemplate = dataTemplate;
```